# javascript: dynamic drop down menu values

Tags: javascript, html

i want to create two drop down form and if i select an item on the first menu the second menu will display corresponding value. for example: if i select "fruit" on the first menu, then the second menu will display "apple", "banana" and so on. it must have values on them so i can insert it into database.

html is as follows:

```
<select id="firstmenu" name="fruit">
<option value="apple">apple</option>
<option value="banana">banana</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select id="secondmenu" name="vegetable">
<option value="carrot">carrot</option>
<option value="celery">celery</option>
</select>
```

javascript; i was thinking using something like this but i lack understanding of javascript

```
<script>
var a=document.forms["myform"]["fruit"].value;
var b=document.forms["myform"]["vegetable"].value;

if (a=="fruit")
{
...
}
</script>
```

could someone give me a code example? help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well,

how about using jQuery?

```js
var items = [{
    name: '---',
    value: '',
    subitems: []
  },
  {
    name: 'Fruit',
    value: 'fruit',
    subitems: [{
        name: 'Apple',
        value: 'apple'
      },
      {
        name: 'Banana',
        value: 'banana'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Vegetable',
    value: 'vegetable',
    subitems: [{
        name: 'Carrot',
        value: 'carrot'
      },
      {
        name: 'Celery',
        value: 'celery'
      }
    ]
  }
];


$(function() {
  var temp = {};

  $.each(items, function() {
    $("<option />")
      .attr("value", this.value)
      .html(this.name)
      .appendTo("#firstmenu");
    temp[this.value] = this.subitems;
  });

  $("#firstmenu").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var menu = $("#secondmenu");

    menu.empty();
    $.each(temp[value], function() {
      $("<option />")
        .attr("value", this.value)
        .html(this.name)
        .appendTo(menu);
    });
  }).change();


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="firstmenu" name="fruit"></select>
<br/>
<select id="secondmenu" name="vegetable"></select>
```

Comment: page doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5):

I used Javascript to create a dropdown menu. Then, if the user chose fruit in the main dropdown menu, I created "fruit" options, and if the user chose vegetables in the main dropdown menu, I created "vegetable" options.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function displayAccordingly() {

            //Call mainMenu the main dropdown menu
            var mainMenu = document.getElementById('mainMenu');

            //Create the new dropdown menu
            var whereToPut = document.getElementById('myDiv');
            var newDropdown = document.createElement('select');
            newDropdown.setAttribute('id',"newDropdownMenu");
            whereToPut.appendChild(newDropdown);

            if (mainMenu.value == "fruit") { //The person chose fruit

                //Add an option called "Apple"
                var optionApple=document.createElement("option");
                optionApple.text="Apple";
                newDropdown.add(optionApple,newDropdown.options[null]);

                //Add an option called "Banana"
                var optionBanana=document.createElement("option");
                optionBanana.text="Banana";
                newDropdown.add(optionBanana,newDropdown.options[null]);

            } else if (mainMenu.value == "vegetable") { //The person chose vegetabes

                //Add an option called "Spinach"
                var optionSpinach=document.createElement("option");
                optionSpinach.text="Spinach";
                newDropdown.add(optionSpinach,newDropdown.options[null]);

                //Add an option called "Zucchini"
                var optionZucchini=document.createElement("option");
                optionZucchini.text="Zucchini";
                newDropdown.add(optionZucchini,newDropdown.options[null]);

            }

        }
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <select id="mainMenu" onchange="displayAccordingly()">
        <option value="">--</option>
        <option value="fruit">Fruit</option>
        <option value="vegetable">Vegetable</option>
        </select>
        <div id="myDiv"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Every time the value of the dropdown menu changes, the function displayAccordingly() runs. It creates a new dropdown menu, and then, if the value of the main dropdown menu is fruit, it adds fruit options to the newly-created dropdown menu, and if the value of the main dropdown menu is vegetables, then it adds vegetable options to the newly-created dropdown menu.

I hope this helps! :)

**EDIT:** If you change the value of the dropdown twice, it creates 2 dropdown menus. I added another variable to fix that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var created = 0;

        function displayAccordingly() {

            if (created == 1) {
                removeDrop();
            }

            //Call mainMenu the main dropdown menu
            var mainMenu = document.getElementById('mainMenu');

            //Create the new dropdown menu
            var whereToPut = document.getElementById('myDiv');
            var newDropdown = document.createElement('select');
            newDropdown.setAttribute('id',"newDropdownMenu");
            whereToPut.appendChild(newDropdown);

            if (mainMenu.value == "fruit") { //The person chose fruit

                //Add an option called "Apple"
                var optionApple=document.createElement("option");
                optionApple.text="Apple";
                newDropdown.add(optionApple,newDropdown.options[null]);

                //Add an option called "Banana"
                var optionBanana=document.createElement("option");
                optionBanana.text="Banana";
                newDropdown.add(optionBanana,newDropdown.options[null]);

            } else if (mainMenu.value == "vegetable") { //The person chose vegetabes

                //Add an option called "Spinach"
                var optionSpinach=document.createElement("option");
                optionSpinach.text="Spinach";
                newDropdown.add(optionSpinach,newDropdown.options[null]);

                //Add an option called "Zucchini"
                var optionZucchini=document.createElement("option");
                optionZucchini.text="Zucchini";
                newDropdown.add(optionZucchini,newDropdown.options[null]);

            }

            created = 1

        }

        function removeDrop() {
            var d = document.getElementById('myDiv');

            var oldmenu = document.getElementById('newDropdownMenu');

            d.removeChild(oldmenu);
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="mainMenu" onchange="displayAccordingly()">
        <option value="">--</option>
        <option value="fruit">Fruit</option>
        <option value="vegetable">Vegetable</option>
        </select>
        <div id="myDiv"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Note: I realized that if you change the value of the main dropdown, you get a new dropdown with the corresponding values. But, if you change the value of the main dropdown _again_, yet another dropdown appears. To fix that, I added a created variable, and at the beginning of displayAccordingly(), if there is already another dropdown menu on the page, it deletes it.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this example may suits you requirement .Here I have set some static content for second option in dynamicdropdown() function.No problem you can make that with your dynamic content by **Option** object.For example

```
document.getElementById("subcategory").options[i] = new Option("key","value",false, false)
```

**i** will be you number of for dynamic values.

Please refer the demo part [DEMO of dynamic drop down menu values](http://www.jyotiranjan.in/livedemo/js/livedemo.php?fn=create-dynamic-drop-down-list.html)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Create dyanamic dropdown list in javascript</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function dynamicdropdown(listindex)
        {
            document.getElementById("subcategory").length = 0;
            switch (listindex)
            {
            case "fruits" :
                document.getElementById("subcategory").options[0]=new Option("Please select fruits","");
                document.getElementById("subcategory").options[1]=new Option("apple","apple");
                document.getElementById("subcategory").options[2]=new Option("banana","banana");
                document.getElementById("subcategory").options[3]=new Option("mangoes","mangoes");
                break;

            case "meats" :
                document.getElementById("subcategory").options[0]=new Option("Please select meats","");
                document.getElementById("subcategory").options[1]=new Option("pigs","pigs");
                document.getElementById("subcategory").options[2]=new Option("chicken","chicken");
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
       </script>
    </head>
    <title>Dynamic Drop Down List</title>
    <body>
        <div class="category_div" id="category_div">Please specify food items:
        <select name="category" class="required-entry" id="category" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
            <option value="">Select food items</option>
            <option value="Php">fruits</option>
            <option value="Javascript">meats</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="sub_category_div" id="sub_category_div">Please select foods:
        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
            document.write('<select name="subcategory" id="subcategory"><option value="">Please select foods</option></select>')
        </script>
        <noscript>
            <select name="subcategory" id="subcategory" >
            <option value="">Please select foods</option>
            </select>
        </noscript>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also refer for more details: [Reference](http://www.jyotiranjan.in/blog/create-dynamic-drop-down-list/)

Answer (score 1):

i am a little confused about your problem, but i just wrote two sample examples for you [DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/player889/E733T/2/) and [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/player889/q5S9k/)

DEMO1 - javascript

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("firstmenu").addEventListener('change',function(e) {ha(e,'firstmenu','secondmenu');}, false);
};

function ha(e,first,second){
    var firstOptions = document.getElementById(first).options;
    var secondOptions = document.getElementById(second).options;
    for(var i = 1, j = firstOptions.length; i < j; i++) {
        secondOptions[i].value = firstOptions[i].value;
        secondOptions[i].text = firstOptions[i].text;
    }
};
```

DEMO2 - javascript

```
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById("firstmenu").addEventListener('change',function(e) {ha(e,'secondmenu');}, false);
   document.getElementById("secondmenu").addEventListener('change',function(e) {ha(e,'firstmenu');}, false);
};
function ha (e,id){
   var index = e.target.selectedIndex;
   document.getElementById(id).selectedIndex = index;
};
```

DEMO1 and DEMO2 have same HTML :

```
<select id="firstmenu" name="City">
    <option value="--">--</option>
    <option value="NY">NY</option>
    <option value="LA">LA</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select id="secondmenu" name="zipCode">
    <option value="--">--</option>
    <option value="10001">10001(NY)</option>
    <option value="90001">90001(LA)</option>
</select>
```

Hope this will help you !!