# How to show another select values if is a value selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a simple form on the my website. Like: `Select 1` and `Select 2`. I want that if I `Select 1` value `Home`, `Select 2` value changes to e.g. `residance`.

How can do that with database? I'm getting these values from database:

`Select 1` values = `Home`, `Otels`

`Select 2` values = if selected `Home` (`residance`, `room`, `apart`), 
if selected `Otel` (`2 stars`, `3stars`, `4stars`)

```
<div class="row pick-size">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-8 col-sm-6">
        <select class="selectpicker" data-size="3" data-style="select-with-transition btn btn-simple">
            <option value="0">Select</option>
            <option value="1">Home</option>
            <option value="2">Otels</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-8 col-sm-6">
        <select class="selectpicker" data-size="3" data-style="select-with-transition btn btn-simple">
            <!--if selected Home show this values-->
            <option value="1">residance</option>
            <option value="2">room</option>
            <option value="3">apart</option>
            <!--if selected Otels show this values-->
            <option value="0">2 stars</option>
            <option value="1">3 stars</option>
            <option value="2">4 stars</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just use the innerHTML JavaScript property to add a different dropdown.

I'd recommend hiding the second dropdown until a value is selected in the first too. This'll provide a better user experience.

But there are some more elegant solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20483470/javascript-dynamic-drop-down-menu-values).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So what do you think, I should get the data from the database. or just use jQuery.